# Wordpress pre get posts order by meta value serialize array

Tags: wordpress, get, posts, pre

i have a custom post type (`cars`) with custom taxonomies (`models` and `countries`)

Every `countries` have a term_meta called like `nearly_countries` for example i have a `loaction` **France** and in `nearly_countries` **Italy** and **Spain**

When i create a post, i'm adding

- `post_meta = position` white the number of position i want in
  taxonomy `models`
- `post_meta = avg_rating` about ratings
- `post_meta    = all_position` with serialize
  `array('term_id_of_model'=>'position_in_model',    'term_id_of_model_term_id_of_country'=>'position_in_model_filter_by_country', 'term_id_of_model_term_id_of_nearly_country'=>'position_in_model_filter_by_nearly_country', 'term_id_of_model_term_id_of_nearly_country'=>'position_in_model_filter_by_nearly_country')`

For the begining below code worked as i expected

```
$taxquery = array();

if (isset($_GET['loc']) && (!empty($_GET['loc']))) {
    $term = get_term_by('slug', $_GET['loc'], 'countries');
    $term_id = $term->term_id;

    $taxquery[] = array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'countries',
        'field'     => 'term_id',
        'terms'     => array($term_id),
        'operator'  => 'IN'
   );
}
$query->set('tax_query', $taxquery);
$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
    'position' => array(
       'key' => 'position'
     ),
     'avg_rating' => array(
        'key' => 'avg_rating'
     )
));
$query->set( 'orderby', array( 'position' => 'ASC', 'avg_rating' => 'DESC', 'rand'=>'DESC' ));
return $query;
```

Then i tried to input and nearly location but i need to replace meta_key `position` with `all_postion` and filter by it

```
$taxquery = array();

if (isset($_GET['loc']) && (!empty($_GET['loc']))) {
    $term = get_term_by('slug', $_GET['loc'], 'countries');
    $term_id = $term->term_id;
    
    $get_nearly = get_term_meta( $term_id, '_nearly_location', true );
    if (!empty($get_nearly)) { 
        $loc_arr = $term_id.','.$get_nearly;
        $countries = explode(",", $loc_arr);
                
        $taxquery[] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'countries',
            'field'     => 'term_id',
            'terms'     => $countries,
            'operator'  => 'IN'
        );
        
    }
    else {
        $taxquery[] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'countries',
            'field'     => 'term_id',
            'terms'     => array($term_id),
            'operator'  => 'IN'
            );  
    }
}
$query->set('tax_query', $taxquery);
$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
    'position' => array(        // i want to
        'key' => 'position'     // replace these
    ),                          // three lines
    'avg_rating' => array(
        'key' => 'avg_rating'
    )
));
$query->set( 'orderby', array( 'position' => 'ASC', 'avg_rating' => 'DESC', 'rand'=>'DESC' ));
return $query;
```

Here is an example of `all_position` meta value `s:236:"a:17:{i:53;i:4;s:6:"53_263";i:1;s:3:"53_";i:4;i:408;i:4;s:4:"408_";i:4;i:13;i:4;s:3:"13_";i:4;i:12;i:4;s:3:"12_";i:4;i:406;i:4;s:4:"406_";i:4;i:407;i:4;s:4:"407_";i:4;s:6:"53_434";i:4;s:6:"53_442";i:4;s:6:"53_454";i:4;s:6:"53_384";i:4;}";`

```
Array
(
    [53] => 4
    [53_263] => 1
    [53_] => 4
    [408] => 4
    [408_] => 4
    [13] => 4
    [13_] => 4
    [12] => 4
    [12_] => 4
    [406] => 4
    [406_] => 4
    [407] => 4
    [407_] => 4
    [53_434] => 4
    [53_442] => 4
    [53_454] => 4
    [53_384] => 4
)
```

where `53` is model `53_263` is country and `53_434`, `53_442`, `53_454`, `53_384` are nearly countries

How can i order by this? Maybe i have to change meta_value `all_position`. I don't want to save them each one in different post_meta

Sorry for my english

Comment: HI Sak, It is not clear at all what you are trying to do.  I guess 'nearly' should be 'nearby' countries.   It is a good idea to make your question VERY clear.  Your question appears to be "How can i order by this?"  What do you mean by 'this'?  Do you mean 'nearby' countries?   Or maybe your 'nearly countries' are the countries that a model is available in?   I would separate those out.  Don't make a key represent two concepts.    Don't store something as an array if you need to sort by items within the array.

It doesn't look like your data structure is supporting how you want to report.

Comment: I have models taxnonomy page filtering by country for example France `domain.com/bmw?loc=France`. So i get all posts which country is France and order them by `post_meta = position` (1,2,3,4). Also i want in same url `domain.com/bmw?loc=France` to get posts whice country is Italy and Spain exaclty after country France. For exampe France positinon_1, France positinon_2, France positinon_3, Italy positinon_1, Italy positinon_2, Spain positinon_1,Spain positinon_2 etc. For position now i'm using `post_meta = all_position`. So i need to filter by `all_position`